# How to change what is shown with CodeLens

Tags: visual-studio

At one point in my development I've changed something and now CodeLens no longer shows me how many references my code has of a method/class, instead it now shows me git information.

Options CodeLens has every option checked but its still not showing up.

[image: What visual studio is showing: Git related info]

This is what I would like to see again.

[image: What I would like visual studio to show: 37 References]

Comment: I have the same problem.  
However, I upgraded from VS 2019 pro to VS2022 pro - I assumed that someone had removed this feature that I use ALL THE TIME.  I tried turning code lens off and on, no joy.  I looked for a .suo file - I don't have one for this project.  I tried resetting the settings to the default -  no joy.  it's broken.

Comment: In an interesting twist, in the official documentation on learn.microsoft.com - under Visual Studio 2022 - it still lists references the same as we used to see on VS2019 and says that they work the same.  No wonder we are confused!